# Trouble mounting a centos NFS export on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: linux, centos, windows, nfs, shared-folders

Hoping somebody can help me out here. Have been struggling with this for a while now.

I have a Centos 6.7 box which has NFS installed.

I have an export/share configured; my exports file is like so...

```
 /diskpool/backup_data *(insecure,rw,sync)
```

NFS is started and I can ping the linux box from the windows box.

I'm trying to mount the NFS share from an elevated command prompt, like so

```
 mount 192.168.16.160:/diskpool/backup_data b:
```

But all I get back is this

```
 Network Error - 53
 Type 'NET HELPMSG 53' for more information.
 C:\Users\Administrator>NET HELPMSG 53
 The network path was not found.
```

I have tried mounting the NFS export locally on the linux box, like so...

```
 mount -t nfs localhost:/diskpool/backup_data /tmp/tmp
```

That works straight away. The location already has data in it and when i run the above command, I can see all of those files in /tmp/tmp, so it definately worked.

Other things I've tried:

- Disabled Windows Firewall completely.
- Disabled IPTables on the Centos box
- Disabled SELinux

I also tried adding /tmp to exports and mounting that, as the 'diskpool' volume is an ZFS volume and I didn't know if that would make a difference. 
This didnt work either, I got the same error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: how about trying this way `mount \\192.168.16.160\diskpool\backup_data b:`

Comment: Same outcome :(